# Bayesian Information Criterion (BIC) for large samples

Tags: regression, bayesian, econometrics, bic

The Bayesian information criterion is defined as $BIC = -2 \text{ln}(L) + k\text{ln}(n)$, where $L$ is the maximized likelihood of the data, and where $n$ is the sample size.

In case of a huge sample size, BIC tend to $\infty$.

Is there any transformation that needs to be done in order to compute the BIC for large samples?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

If I got you correctly:

As BIC is basically used to *compare* models (as AIC or MDL), you can apply any monotone transformation as long as you do it for both of the compared models.

Comment: Thank you for your post. What transformation would you suggest?

Comment: @Mariam, but just for clarification: what is your confuse confuse about $\mathrm{BIC} \to \infty$?

Comment: Well I need to compute the BIC for a regression model, where the dependent variable is of length 7000. R returns -Inf for BIC. I am not sure how to compute the information criterion in this case.

Comment: @Mariam Hm... I guess it's rather a computation issue. Try to insert (probably somewhere in the process *before* you compute BIC) logarithmization (I can't see your computation, but I guess you can reduce the numbers you get by applying something like logarithm).

Answer (score 1):

Normalize BIC by dividing
By 2n.
Let the likelihood function
 $L = \prod_{i=1}^n p( x_i | \theta)$.
Then when the sample size $n$ is large then the influence of the $K \log n$ term becomes negligible
and the normalized BIC converges
To the cross entropy of the fitted
Model with the density which generated
the data.
To see this note
$\frac{BIC}{2n} = -(1/n) \log L+ (k/n) \log (n) 
=  -(1/n) \sum_{i=1}^n \log p( x_i |\theta) + (k/n) \log (n)$
Under usual regularity conditions 
First normalized log likelihood term on right hand side converges to a number and second term on right hand side converges to zero.